# Find the Laurent series expansion of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(1-2z)}$ about $z=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I rewrite $f(z)$ using partial fractions to get $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{2}{1-2z}$.

We need powers of $\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)$
So how do I rewrite $\frac{1}{z}$?

So I rewrite it as $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)}$
And I write it as $2\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)$

How do I get the binomial expansion in powers of $\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)$?

Comment: $z = \frac{1}{2} + \bigl(z-\frac{1}{2}\bigr)$

Comment: so the expression $\frac{1}{z}$ becomes $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)}$?

Comment: Yes. Do you know how to continue from there?

Comment: I think you then first factor out the $\frac{1}{2}$ and then write the expression with $-1$ power and find the binomial expansion? You then do the same but after factorizing out the Z.

Comment: The big trouble I have is after finding the binomial expansion, how to find out for which value does |Z| converge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac1{z(1-2z)}=\frac1z+\frac2{1-2z}=\frac1{\frac12+\left(z-\frac12\right)}-\frac1{z-\frac12}=\frac2{1+2\left(z-\frac12\right)}-\frac1{z-\frac12}=$$

$$2\left(1-2\left(z-\frac12\right)+4\left(z-\frac12\right)^2-\ldots\right)-\frac1{z-\frac12}=$$

$$=-\frac1{z-\frac12}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n2^n\left(z-\frac12\right)^n$$

The above is true whenever

$$\left|2\left(z-\frac12\right)\right|<1\iff\left|z-\frac12\right|<\frac12$$

Comment: what expansion is that?

Comment: Which one: the one in the second line? The one of $$\frac1{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n$$ which is the geometric series, of course. It is valid whenever $\;|x|<1\;$ .

Comment: In my class notes we always use binomial but everyone here works it out using geometric. Would it still work with binomial expansion?

Comment: I can't see how you people "always" work with binomial expansions: many, many many expansions are **not** binomial, among them all the trigonometric, the exponential, the geometric, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The series is the following:

$\sum _{k=1}^\infty(-2)^{k}(z-\frac{1}{2})^{n}$.

That is the Laurent series for $f(z)$.

Hope this helped.

By the way:

Here is how to find the disk of convergence:

We'll find the pole of $f(z)$. To do that we must set:

$z(1-2z)=0$

This is the same as,

$z-2z^2=0$

This has two zeros at $z=\frac{1}{2}$ and $z=0$.

Theorem:

If $\beta_{1}$ and $\beta_{2}$ are two singularities of a function $f(z)$ then can be expressed as a series expansion then:

$|\alpha-\beta_{1}|<|z|<|\alpha-\beta_{2}|$

Where $\alpha$ is the point you expanded the series about.

In this case,

$0<|z|<|\frac{1}{2}|$

Or, $|z|<\frac{1}{2}$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I highly doubt that what you say is the "Laurent series: *actually* is as $\;z=\frac12\;$ is a simple pole of the function, yet what you give is a power series, hereby rendering this as an analycity point...yet you didn't show *any* of your work, so it's hard to know where the mistake is.